# What open source GIS is a good alternative to ArcGIS for editing - with main interest in the Freehand mode

Tags: open-source, gis

I am looking for an alternative for ArcGIS for editing. Tasks are mostly editing new polylines. An important ArcGIS feature for this is the Freehand mode. QGIS for instants offers something similar, but far away from accuracy. The task is mainly to copy routes from a paper into GIS. So a good accurcy is difficult to obtain. However, polylines need to look smooth. Which is not given by QGIS.